# How do I add Qt class in a project makefile?

Tags: c++, qt, makefile

I have a big project which builds through a Makefile. And I must not change the `.pro` file of it.
Now I'm trying to use Qt in a project so I created these files:

```
//Emitter.h
#ifndef EMITTER_H
#define EMITTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDBusInterface>
#include <QDBusAbstractAdaptor>
#include <QDBusVariant>

class Emitter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Emitter();

private:
    QDBusInterface * m_interface;
    QString m_interfaceName;
};

#endif // EMITTER_H
```

and
    //Emitter.cpp
    #include "Emitter.h"

```
Emitter::Emitter()
{
}
```

Then I added Emitter.o to a `*.o` list in MakeFile.
If I try to build I receive an error:

`Emitter.h:4: error: QObject: No such file or directory`

which is normal as the Makefile doesn't know about Qt headers at the moment.

What must be done to a Makefile to make it build?

Answer (score 1):

You should add

cpp fileS to your make file. But note - that before you should make another one cpp from your header with MOC (because you use Q_OBJECT)

e.g.

```
moc_emitter.cpp: 
   /PATH/TO/moc $(DEFINES) $(INCPATH) emitter.h -o moc_emitter.cpp
```

Then .o sections

```
moc_emitter.cpp.o: moc_emitter.cpp
        $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o moc_emitter.o moc_emitter.cpp
emitter.o: emitter.cpp
     $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o emitter.o emitter.cpp
```

And only than add new .0 files to OBJECTS section.

- You should add different Qt PATHes for moc and compiles (info about Qt headers)

Comment: Can you please explain why moc_emitter.cpp.o is needed? It's not used when creating emitter.o.

Comment: Qt's moc tool generates implementations for the functions declared by Q_OBJECT and for all the signals you defined in your .h.  This is what is contained in your moc_emitter.cpp.  So in order to use these functions, your must link with the moc_emitter.cpp.o

Answer (score 0):

add the qt `include` folder to the include list

you will also need to run the `moc` on emmitter.h and compile the generated file